# Question about how to get openssl to work with Apache

Tags: apache, openssl, self-signed-certificate

So I need to create a self signed certificate for a web page I am making with Apache. I have looked up and followed different sets of instructions but I am missing something. I am a student and have never used ssl or apache. Apache is installed, the localhost page is up and showing the content of the html docs I've edited. OpenSSL is installed. So it's probably me missing something. I keep getting messages like this

```
C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin>openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024 genrsa: Can't 
open "server.key" for writing, Permission denied

C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin>openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout 
mysitename.key -out mysitename.crt
Generating a RSA private key
..........................+++++
...................................+++++
writing new private key to 'mysitename.key'
req: Can't open "mysitename.key" for writing, Permission denied
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing private key creation.

1 `Private key` creation

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
```

result

```
$ cat server.key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAr2E2AUJ+TbptdBVMxYHmUzRpOflP69SX03NyuKh75XIO4tp6
...
Fhe+gzT7QD7Dg9SdP45eQWy5jtDYu4HIcy/ha0sikBi9+8pSs6qo
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

2 `Certification Signing Request` creation with #1's private key

```
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

common needs `localhost` other options are default or your.

```
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:localhost
```

result

```
$ cat server.csr
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIICijCCAXICAQAwRTELMAkGA1UEBhMCQVUxEzARBgNVBAgMClNvbWUtU3RhdGUx
...
sDS9gxYfks/7zxvtBzOWR3ZZzjlenpyqqu4aYZyb
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

3 `Certification` creation

```
 openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

result

```
$ cat server.crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDOTCCAiECFB0jWF04/GTmwfh8Ph1Zqeulb0IuMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMFkx
...
nrp0uU09oePMMMEn5g==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

4 `local server` code by python (file name is server.py)

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import ssl

class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'Hello, world!')

httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 4443), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)

httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, 
        keyfile="./server.key", 
        certfile='./server.crt', server_side=True)

httpd.serve_forever()
```

5 `local server` test

```
python server.py
```

[image]

Comment: wow thank you this is a great answer, I'll post later to say if that worked.  Just one question... might be dumb, but is using the python server going to make me have to code with python or use specific parameters I am not already using? I am just making some simple html pages and assigning ssl to a login page; for a school course.

Comment: It is normal python program, just name is server.py. you don't need to install any server package for running this example program but you have to write #4 code example with python.py file. Good luck, if you works on your local PC, please give me thumbs up.